# How to do a latlag array list save in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My app looks like this]I am developing an app where users can click on the map to add some custom marker for creating a polygon on the map (See the above image). Now I want that when the user opens the app again, it shows those custom markers that were added before.

I want to achieve it with the help of Firebase Realtime Database. When the user clicks on the map, that marker location (in the form of lat,lang) should be saved to the database and later should be shown again from the database when the app is opened. I'm unable to write Firebase database code to save those custom marker points.

I have no idea how to achieve it. Here is what I have already done:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    //Initialize variable
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;

    GoogleMap gmap;

    CheckBox checkBox;
    SeekBar seekRed,seekGreen,seekBlue;
    Button btDraw,btClear,btSave;

    Polygon polygon = null;
    List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<>();

    int red=0,green=0,blue=0;

    private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference().child("Field");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assign Variable
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        seekRed = findViewById(R.id.seek_red);
        seekGreen = findViewById(R.id.seek_green);
        seekBlue = findViewById(R.id.seek_blue);
        btDraw = findViewById(R.id.bt_draw);
        btClear = findViewById(R.id.bt_clear);
        btSave = findViewById(R.id.bt_save);


        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                //get CheckBox
                if (b){
                    if (polygon == null) return;;
                    //Fill Polygon Color
                    polygon.setFillColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
                }else {
                    //Unfill polygon color is unchecked
                    polygon.setFillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }
        });

        btDraw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Draw Polyline on map
                if (polygon != null) polygon.remove();
                //Create PolygonOption
                PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().addAll(latLngList).clickable(true);
                polygon = gmap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
                //Set Polygon Stroke
                polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    //Fill Color
                    polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                }
            }
        });

        btClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Clear All
                if (polygon != null) polygon.remove();
                for (Marker marker : markerList) marker.remove();
                latLngList.clear();
                markerList.clear();
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                seekRed.setProgress(0);
                seekGreen.setProgress(0);
                seekBlue.setProgress(0);
            }
        });


        seekRed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        seekGreen.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        seekBlue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        //Initialize fused Location
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //Check permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //When permission granted
            //call method
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            //When permission denied
            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        //Initialize task Location
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                //When success
                if (location != null){
                    //Sync map
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            //Initialize lat lng
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            //Create Marker options
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here");
                            //Zoom map
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
                            //Add marker on map
                            googleMap.addMarker(options);

                            gmap = googleMap;

                            gmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                                    //Create Marker Option
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                                    //Create Marker
                                    Marker marker = gmap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                    //Add Latlang and Marker
                                    latLngList.add(latLng);
                                    markerList.add(marker);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 44){
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //When permission granted
                //call method
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        switch (seekBar.getId()){
            case R.id.seek_red:
                red = progress;
                break;
            case R.id.seek_green:
                green = progress;
                break;
            case R.id.seek_blue:
                blue = progress;
                break;

        }
        if (polygon != null) {

            //Set Polygon Stroke
            polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
            if (checkBox.isChecked())
                //Fill Color
                polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the code for Firebase? I mean how do you save it? Right now what I can see is you already implemented the map only

Comment: Can you please reconsider the question? At first, I made a framing error.